# Searching an entire drive for plaintext passwords

Tags: linux, windows, security, grep, passwords

I have an encrypted database of about 6000 unique passwords, and I want to search about 1TB of data for any instance of these passwords.  I am using Cygwin, but I could have the drive available in a real linux environment if I needed to.

I have a file "**ClientPasswords.txt**" which contains every unique password only once, one password per line.  I am trying to compare every file in my T:/ drive to this list.

I am using this command:

```
grep -nr -F -f ClientPasswords.txt /cygdrive/t 2> SuspectFiles.txt
```

My goal is to generate a list of all files, "**SuspectFiles.txt**", that contain any known password in our password database in plaintext so that we can redact sensitive information from the drive.

Currently, it is getting a ton of false positives, including some that don't seem to match anything in the list.  I have already eliminated all passwords that are fewer than 6 characters, can be found in the dictionary (or are otherwise known client names), or are just numbers.

I would like to:

1. Limit it to a select few filetypes (txt, csv, xls, xlsx, doc, docx, etc.)
2. Eliminate all compressed files (or find a way to search inside them)
3. Limit snippet output to prevent dumping entire binary files into the output file.

Anyone done something similar, or know of an easier way to search for these improperly documented passwords from a blacklist?  I have also played around with the Windows program "Agent Ransack", but it seems much more limited than grep.

Thanks!

Comment: Confused - Are the passwords in ClientPasswords.txt encrypted? Is this your 6000 list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you want to do is make a list of all files on drive T that are of the right type, and output that to a list of target file names.  Use a shell script:

```
for i in txt csv xls xlsx doc docx;
do
    find /cygdrive/t  -name \*.$i >> target_file_names.txt
done
```

Now that you have the target file names, you can search your passwords amongst those target file names.

```
for target_file in `cat target_file_names.txt`
do
    for pwd in `cat ClientPasswords.txt`
    do
        grep -l $pwd $target_file > /dev/null
        test $? -eq 0 && echo $target_file has password $pwd
    done 
done
```

Something like that should work.  You might have to tweak it a little.